# Jacobi Matrix for different functions

Tags: real-analysis

How to find the Jacobi-Matrix for the following functions?

$f:(x,y)\rightarrow x^2+y^2$

$f: (x,y)\rightarrow \sqrt{x^2+y^2}$

$f:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow \mathbb{R}: x\rightarrow \sum_{i=1}^nx_i^2$

$f:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow \mathbb{R}: x\rightarrow ||x||_2$

---

For the first one I have an idea, but for the others I have no idea. Can someone provide me with a solution/hint/Source where I can find more on this kind of problems?

Comment: The third and fourth are generalizations of the first and second

Comment: yes, thats right. So in fact I have to solve the last two, right?

Comment: IMHO you should first solve the first and the second. It would help you understand the general case. Something else : do you know how the Jacobi matrix of a map at some point is defined ?